# accessing test classes from javaagent using maven-surefire

Tags: instrumentation, maven-surefire-plugin, byte-buddy, javaagents

I am trying to run an analysis that would capture the values of the locator when running selenium test. Having a large number of projects and versions to test, I want to avoid directly modifying the project files whatsoever, hence, I resorted to the use of a javaagent (with ByteBuddy). The idea is to instrument the test classes so they will get me the information I need. Hence, in the pom.xml of the project I am analyzing i had to setup the surefire-plugin as follow

```xml
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>@{argLine} -javaagent:\path\to\my\agent.jar</argLine>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

The argLine field allows me to attach the agent to the surefire process and the forkCount forces surefire to only use one JVM which should allow me to have a visibility on all the classes that are loaded (I think).

As for the agent, I have the premain method as follow

```java
public static void premain(final String agentArgs,
                           final Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("Starting to collect metrics");

    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
            .type(ElementMatchers.any())
            .transform(new LocatorReporterTransformer())
            .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
            .installOn(inst);
}
```

I used the ElementMatchers.any() to be sure to be able to see all the classes that were intercepted by my agent. In the LocatorReporterTransormer class, i have the method transform(...) as follow

```java
@Override
public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder,
                                        TypeDescription typeDescription,
                                        ClassLoader classLoader,
                                        JavaModule javaModule) {

    System.out.println(typeDescription.getName());
    return builder;
}
```

My goal was to capture some of the classes from my tests, but it seems they are never loaded in the JVM, which is weird to me. Thus, my question is: How can I safeley add a javaagent to surefire and make sure it can access all the classes? Is there a way for the javaagent to capture all the subprocess from a target?

Comment: Are you sure the agent is never loaded? Maybe you need to register a default ignore matcher to not ignore any classes (`none()`). Also, I do not know why you register the eager self-injection, it does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter, I think he means that it looks as if the target classes are never loaded, so your suggestion to use `.ignore(none())` should help. If he reports back that it does not help, I have other questions on my mind, but usually that's what does the trick. @kabinja, did you consider writing a simple JUnit, TestNG, Spock or whatever test tool extension for your reporting needs? Why use a big cannon like ByteBuddy to shoot a little bird?

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. So after doing some tests, I realized that my issue was coming from the fact that even though I put the forkCount to 0, I still had different processes and JVM loaded. So my solution involved passing the agent as an argument in MAVEN_OPTS and running the tests with mvn test -forkMode:never. This fits my use case, but sounds a bit dirty. If someone comes us with  better solution, I will accept it otherwise, I will put this one. As for why I use bytebuddy, I will also need to do other manipulation in the future, but that was the minimal case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes were not all visible because more than one process was executing. It seems that the **forkCount = 0** d did not do the trick. One solution is to actually attach the agent on the maven process using the MAVEN_OPTS and then use **fockMode = never**. Here is the implementation that works in my case:

```
set "MAVEN_OPTS=-javaagent:\path\to\agent.jar"
mvn test -DforkMode=never
```